# Extract words with different lengths from vector

Tags: r

I have two types of results which are differentiated with the words DailyMean and Peak. I would like to extract the words DailyMean and Peak from filenames.

```
    filenames  <- list.files(path = folder.out, pattern = 
    ls.extensions[[T]][type])
    "01611500-DailyMean.out" "01611500-Peak.out"      
    "03180500-DailyMean.out" "03180500-Peak.out"

Used substr and regexec but could only extract a fixed length
    "Dail" "Peak" "Dail" "Peak"

The result should be as follows
    "DailyMean" "Peak" "DailyMean" "Peak"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `sub` to extract everything between a hyphen and `".out"`.

```
sub(".*-(.*)\\.out$", "\\1", x)
#[1] "DailyMean" "Peak"      "DailyMean" "Peak"
```

---

We can also use `qdapRegex::ex_between` which does the same thing with no regex

```
unlist(qdapRegex::ex_between(x, "-", ".out"))
```

**data**

```
x <- c("01611500-DailyMean.out", "01611500-Peak.out", "03180500-DailyMean.out", 
       "03180500-Peak.out")
```